# Change MUI Checkbox checkmark color

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

Material UI's [MUI](https://mui.com/) library for React uses the background color of the container element for the color of the checkmark inside the checkbox. This works well in light mode, but on top of dark backgrounds I want the check mark to be white. How to do this?

I tried setting `color`, but that changes the accent color not the check mark color. I tried setting `backgroundColor`, but that leaves a thick white border around the checkbox.

I also tried building my own custom icons from scratch in SVG, but I couldn't figure out how to get MUI to attach all the CSS classes that it uses for icons.

I'd be happy to use one of the icons in [MUI's icon library](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=check) but I didn't see one that supported controlling both the background color and the checkmark color.

I've even tried the huge hack of placing an absolutely-positioned `<div>` in back of the checkbox, but that doesn't work when the checkbox isn't checked. And I assume that there's gotta be a better way to do it!

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-checkbox-check-mark-color-ss9dr6

```
<div
  className="App"
  style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#333", padding: 20 }}
>
  <div>How to get a MUI checkbox with a white checkmark?</div>
  <Checkbox
    defaultChecked
    sx={{
      "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
        fontSize: 28,
        color: "green",
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }
    }}
  />
  <Checkbox
    defaultChecked
    sx={{
      "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": { fontSize: 28, color: "green" }
    }}
  />
  <div>
    Desired: white check mark (like left example above) but without the
    white border.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a workaround that might help. The main problem is that we can't adjust the size of the SVG within the material, which is causing the border issue.

```
<Checkbox
  defaultChecked
  sx={{
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      fontSize: 28,
      color: "green",
    },
    "&.MuiCheckbox-root": {
      borderRadius: 0,
      padding: 0,
    },
    "&.Mui-checked": {
      backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    "& svg": {
      scale: "1.4",
    },
  }}
/>;
```

The result will look like this. The checkbox size may increase slightly, but the border disappears after adding the scale.

[image]

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround. The size issue is easy to fix by changing `font-size` to 20.

One problem: this workaround removes the faint circular animation of the border (or the outline?) that shows up when you check or uncheck the checkbox. This isn't a total deal-breaker, but I'd prefer to retain this animation, so I'll keep looking for other solutions.